# windows bat file to find a new file with specific naming format from a location

Tags: batch-file

I need a Windows batch to find a file with the naming convention(`sujith-dd-mm-yy.txt`) from a location. And everyday that location gets updated with a new file of the same naming format except a change in the date part of the file name. file name: `sujith-dd-mm-yy.txt` location: `C:\program files\sujith ..`

Comment: You'll need to do your own research and show your efforts if you expect any help on SO, because write-my-code-for-me questions are off-topic here!

Answer (score 1):

List the files in the desired format (use wildcards: `?` means "any character") with `dir` sorted by date (`/od`) in "just-filename-format" (`/b`)

use `for /f` to set a variable to the filename (it does it for every file, so the latest one "wins")

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in ('dir /od /b "sujith-??-??-????.txt"') do set file=%%i
echo the latest file is %file%
```

Of course this would also return a file `sujith-ab-cd-wrgl.txt`, as long as the dashes are on the correct positions, but such a filename should be unlikely